# Summarized table column being recognized

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to add a filter to my final output count using an aggregate column added to a summarized table. The dax formula isn't recognizing the aggregate column as valid. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.tbl[Arrests] is the problem.

```
VAR tbl =
    SUMMARIZE(
        dimEmployee,
        dimEmployee[wkEmployee],
        "Arrests", DISTINCTCOUNT(dimBookingEvent[BookingSystemId])
    )
var individualsMultipleArrest = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(tbl), tbl[Arrests] > 1)

RETURN
    individualsMultipleArrest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is due to the way DAX handles tables and columns generated within expressions. When you create a table inside a DAX expression using `SUMMARIZE`, you can't directly reference the columns as if they were part of the existing data model. You'll need to work within the context of that table to access the columns.

You need to use the `FILTER` function inside the `CALCULATE` to filter the `tbl` variable based on the conditions you want to apply.

```
VAR tbl =
    SUMMARIZE(
        dimEmployee,
        dimEmployee[wkEmployee],
        "Arrests", DISTINCTCOUNT(dimBookingEvent[BookingSystemId])
    )
VAR individualsMultipleArrest = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(tbl),
    FILTER(
        tbl,
        [Arrests] > 1
    )
)

RETURN
    individualsMultipleArrest
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This resolved my issue and I appreciate you explaining why DAX syntax was off.